# Use the annotations inside the method

Tags: java, annotations, jax-rs

Is there a way to use the value of the annotation inside the same method that it has been declared ?

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Path(CONSTANTS.PATH1)
public MyModel getInfo(
            @PathParam(CONSTANTS.ID) String id, 
            @Context HttpServletRequest request, 
            @Context HttpServletResponse response) {
    ...
}
```

In the above example, is it possible to use the value of  `@Path`(CONSTANTS.PATH1) inside the method? I can directly use the value of CONSTANTS.PATH1, but if it possible to get it from annotations itself ?

Comment: You are looking for the Java reflection api.

Comment: Sounds like an [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What's the exact use case? Maybe something using UriInfo or UriBuilder would work. Otherwise you will have to use some reflection

Comment: And that may not work if the annotations don't have a retention policy of `RUNTIME`.

Comment: @Path has retention `RUNTIME`.

Comment: If its complicated (Uri Info, UriBuilder) and not straight forward, using the same string constant is easy way then.